# Reason why in Gaussian integers, norm divisibility may not lead to divisibility.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

It is taken as true (with a very easy proof) for Gaussian integers, that for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb {Z}[i]$, if $\beta \mid \alpha$ then $N_{\beta} \mid N_\alpha$ in $\mathbb {Z}$. It would be an aid for easier check of $\beta \mid \alpha$ in $\mathbb {Z}$, provided the reverse is true, but it is usually not true, as the following example shows:
$$\alpha = 14+3i,\qquad\beta= 4 +5i.$$
Here, $N_{\beta} = 41$, $N_{\alpha}=205$, but the ratio $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{14+3i}{4+5i}$, after rationalization $ = \frac{71}{41} -\frac{58}{41}i \notin \mathbb {Z}$.

There should be some reason behind this, I hope, that can be expressed geometrically and/or algebraically .

Comment: Do you have pictures in your mind when you think about Gaussian integers?

Comment: Yes, I think of a plane with the x-axis of reals, and imaginary numbers on y-axis. It is the same as Argand diagram, with an explicit representation of lattice points, as can be on a graph paper with unit intervals being drawn on both axis.

Comment: An easier counterexample that might give some insight: $\alpha = 2 + i$, $\beta = 2 - i$.

Comment: In the original example, the irreducible factorizations are: $\alpha = (2-i) (5+4i)$, $\beta = i (5-4i)$.

Comment: You should really look at $\frac{2+i}{2-i} $, a quotient of two different prime elements (whereas $1+i$ and $1-i$ are the same prime element, since their quotient is the unit $i$)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I hope you must have factored the original example, by hit and trial. I tried to take the product of conjugates on both the l.h.s. & r.h.s. of: $(5 +  4i)(a +bi)= 14+ 3i \implies$ product of : (i) $(4a-5b) + i(5a+4b) = 14 + 3i,$ and the conjugate : (ii) $(4a-5b) - i(5a+4b) = 14 - 3i.$ This also lead nowhere as $a^2 + b^2 =5$ was obtained.

Comment: I was actually using Maxima's `gcfactor` function which does exactly factorization of Gaussian integers into irreducibles (and then I touched it up a bit to normalize the irreducibles into the quadrant $-\pi/4 < \theta \le \pi/4$).

Comment: @DanielSchepler My earlier comment is having typos, the correct one follows : $(5 + 4i)(a +bi)= 14+ 3i \implies$ product of : (i) $(5a-4b) + i(4a+5b) = 14 + 3i,$ and the conjugate : (ii) $(5a-4b) - i(4a+5b) = 14 - 3i.$ This also lead nowhere as get by product:  $(5a-4b)^2 + (4a+5b)^2 =196 +9 = 205 \implies 41(a^2 + b^2) = 205 \implies a^2 +b^2 = 5$. I also do not know, but the Maxima fn.must be approximating then.

Comment: @reuns I am sorry, but am unable to understand that if you are really referring to my question.

Comment: The comment by reuns gets to the heart of your question. It's true that $5|5$, but it's not true that $(2-i)|(2+i)$. That's a minimal example of the phenomenon you're asking about, @jitender. It's one of those pairs of non-associated primes that have the same norm, but not the same set of multiples.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs    Regarding the values of $\alpha = 2 +i$, $\beta = 2-i$, $N_{alpha} = N_{beta}=5$, yet $\beta \nmid \alpha$, as the rationalized fraction is : $\frac{3}{5} + \frac{4}{5}i$ . It is better with this being a simpler example if I could send a grid on which the two points are plotted. So, for that I am uploading a simpled diagram (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKqi7.jpg), that shows what else I can think of the grid.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs    Also, to draw in response to your answer, grids for the subrings :$1+i, 3+2i$, I hope can only be made for each in a separate graph with each having some lattice points (multiples) of each. You have implicitly referred to drawing the conjugates also for the point in their corresponding grid. How does that help, and can be plotted in the same diagram, if both the point (say, $1+i$) need multiples thereof and need to plot the lattice points for $1-i$ also.

Answer (score 7):

It will help to think in terms of the factorizations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into irreducible elements.  Now, the irreducibles of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ consist of a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ times one of:

- $1+i$
- $a \pm bi$ where $0 < b < a$ and $a^2 + b^2 = p$ is a prime integer (i.e. irreducible as an element of $\mathbb{Z}$) with $p \equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  (And for each such prime $p$, there exists a unique such pair $a, b$.)
- $p$ where $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ is a prime integer.

Now, $\beta \mid \alpha$ if and only if the exponent of each irreducible in the factorization of $\alpha$ is greater than or equal to the corresponding exponent in $\beta$.  However, looking at the norms of irreducibles, you see that for irreducibles of the second type above, $a + bi$ and $a - bi$ have the same norm.  Therefore, taking the norm loses the distinction between these two irreducibles, but the divisibility condition does make the distinction (since $a+bi$ is not a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ times $a-bi$).

In the original example, $\alpha = 14 + 3i$ has irreducible factorization $\alpha = (2-i) (5+4i)$ while $\beta = 4+5i$ is irreducible itself and is equivalent to $\beta = i (5-4i)$.  Therefore, the failure of $\beta$ to divide $\alpha$ comes from the distinction between $5-4i$ and $5+4i$ which the norm collapses.

Comment: Yes, this gets to the heart of it. A lot of the primes in $\Bbb Z[i]$ come in pairs, $\alpha=a+bi$ and $\overline{\alpha}=a-bi$, where $a^2+b^2=p$ is a rational prime congruent to $1$, modulo $4$. Any Gaussian integer whose norm is a multiple of $p$ is a multiple of $\alpha$ or of $\overline{\alpha}$, but not necessarily of both.

Answer (score 5):

In $\Bbb Z$, all of the multiples of $n$ are easy to visualize: they form a regular sequence of points along the number line, spaced $n$ units apart. That's the subring $n\Bbb Z$. It's an expanded copy of $\Bbb Z$, contained within $\Bbb Z$.

In $\Bbb Z[i]$, something similar happens. Within the lattice of Gaussian integers, all of the multiples of $\alpha$ form a grid that looks like an enlargement of the entire grid; it's formed by taking $\Bbb Z$-linear combinations of $\alpha$ and $i\alpha$. You should draw a couple of these to get a feel for it. The subring $(1+i)\Bbb Z[i]$ is nice to look at, and you should try something like $(3+2i)\Bbb Z[i]$ as well.

Now, multiples of $\alpha=(3+2i)$ (norm 13) are just points in that subring/sublattice. Look at it, and then look at the sublattice generated by $\overline{\alpha}=(3-2i)$ as well. Note that they do not contain the same points. Any point in the lattice generated by $\alpha$ is a multiple of $\alpha$; any point in the lattice generated by $\overline{\alpha}$, but not in the one generated by $\alpha$, is not a multiple of alpha, even though its norm is a multiple of $13$. (The points that these two lattices have in common are precisely the Gaussian integer multiple of $13$.)

Does that help?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs    In response to your answer for drawing grids for the subrings: $1+i, 3+2i$, I hope can only be made for each in a separate graph with each having some lattice points (multiples) of each. You have implicitly referred to drawing the conjugates also for the point in their corresponding grid. How does that help, and can be plotted in the same diagram, if both the point (say, $1+i$) need multiples thereof and need to plot the lattice points for $1-i$ also.

Comment: So, there's a difference between $1+i$ and $3+2i$. The conjugate of $1+i$ is really the "same" prime, because its ratio to $1+i$ is a unit. That's not true for the Gaussian primes whose norms are *odd* rational primes, such as $3+2i$. In other words: $1+i$ and $1-i$ give you the same grid. $3+2i$ and $3-2i$ do not.

Comment: For this purpose, $2+i$ is just as good an example as $3+2i$. They both have the same properties that are relevant to what we're talking about here.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs    I cannot understand as to me it appears that drawing multiples of either $1+i, 1-i$ or $3+2i, 3-2i$ on the same graph leads to two straight lines, passing through origin and crossing each other at right angles, for 4 values in each by two multiples of with $1,-1$. I mean : $1+i, -1-i, 1-i, -1-i$ on one graph, and similarly $3+2i, 3-2i, -3-2i, -3+2i$ on other graph.

Comment: The number $3-2i$ is not a multiple of $3+2i$.

Comment: I agree but on graph its the same type of lines as for $1+i, 1-i$. I am uploading the graph for 2 points each of $1+i, 1-i$, with address : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSJK9.jpg . The graph of $3+2i, 3-2i$ is similar only.

Comment: Shall we move to chat?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs    Yes, definitely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70975/discussion-between-g-tony-jacobs-and-jitender).

Comment: The 5 at the end of your answer should be 13.

Comment: @KCd, thanks. Fixed that.

Answer (score 4):

From your choice of example and notation I wonder if this is coming from pages 2 and 3 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf or the similarity is a coincidence.

In any case, the basic reason you should not expect norm divisibility to imply actual divisibility in $\mathbf Z[i]$ is that norms can *lose* essential information.  There are Gaussian integers with the same norm that do *not* have the same factors, such as $1+2i$ and $1-2i$, which both have norm $5$ but neither divides the other (in fact they are relatively prime in $\mathbf Z[i]$). In general you can *not* reconstruct $\alpha$ up to unit multiple in $\mathbf Z[i]$ from knowledge of ${\rm N}(\alpha)$, so why should you expect divisibility of norms to imply divisibility of elements?

(In $\mathbf Z[i]$ there are some situations where information about the norm *is* equivalent to information about the original element, such as being invertible. In certain cases there is equivalence for divisibility, such as $(1+i) \mid \alpha \Leftrightarrow 2 \mid {\rm N}(\alpha)$, but you should not expect such things to be true in general.)

Consider an analogue with polynomials and degrees: instead of ${\rm N}(\alpha\beta) = {\rm N}(\alpha){\rm N}(\beta)$ in $\mathbf Z[i]$ we have $\deg(fg) = \deg f + \deg g$ in $\mathbf R[x]$, so a polynomial analogue of $\alpha \mid \beta \Rightarrow {\rm N}(\alpha) \mid {\rm N}(\beta)$ is $f \mid g \Rightarrow\deg f \leq \deg g$. If I told you two polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbf R[x]$ satisfy $\deg f \leq \deg g$, would you expect $f$ should divide $g$?

Comment: I hope your answer's last paragraph serves as a rigorous proof too. If not, then would request one, or a source that deals with that. Yes, my example is derived from pg. 3 of the stated source by you.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the last paragraph serving as a rigorous proof. A rigorous proof of what?

Comment: A rigorous proof of the issue that the reverse (divisibility of norms)  will not lead to divisibility of the algebraic numbers. May be it does not need a rigorous proof, and neither is one possible.

Comment: That needs just an *example*, and you have already been pointed to such examples in several answers, e.g., $2+i$ and $2-i$, $3+2i$ and $3-2i$, and $1+2i$ and $1-2i$. I mention that last example in my answer, but not in the last paragraph. I did not give full details. Work it out on your own.

Comment: Attempted complete proof: norms lack exact information of underlying algebraic integer, as shown with a counter-example of :$1+2i, 1-2i$, which have same norm. $\frac{1+2i}{1-2i} = \frac{-3}{5} + \frac{4}{5}i$. It is further elaborated by fact that norm is distance from origin, as a given number is a point in 2-D plane. It is not possible that all points with same distance are multiples of each other, This property was true in simple integers, as each point with same modulus is derivable by reaching via multiplicative operators, from another of same norm.

Comment: In continuation to the earlier comment: It is precisely the lack of any multiple in algebraic integers, of reaching one point from the other with the same norm, in general, that restricts the reverse (i.e., the norms' divisibility implies the algebraic numbers' divisibility).

Comment: In turn this points to un-reachability, a geometric concept that seems solution by linear algebra concepts of matrix operations, that I am not aware of application for algebraic integers.

Comment: I hope my attempt shows clearly what I perceive as proof (rigorous proof), i.e. one based on some algebraic notations to express a given fact..

Comment: Thanks for kick-starting me into this way of reasoning, that was only implicitly clear earlier. I have found some beginner material (that a person, like me, with not any knowledge of abstract algebra can also understand) at : http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/ANT10.pdf I hope to read as much as I can, and request for help.

Comment: It is not directly relevant that the norm  is a (squared) distance. Similar ideas apply in some real quadratic rings like $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{2}]$, where the norm is positive and negative, e.g., $1+2\sqrt{2}$ and $1-2\sqrt{2}$ have equal norm and are not unit multiples; there are infinitely many units: all $\pm (1+\sqrt{2})^n$ for $n \in \mathbf Z$. And you are incorrect to say it is *not* possible for all Gaussian integers with equal norm to be multiples of each other. Try elements of norm $2$. My point earlier was that there are *examples* to the contrary, not that all norm values are examples.